# shared_from_this() from another thread (a member thread function)

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, boost-thread

In my code I use `boost::threads` and I have a class that runs a thread via a member function called `fnThread()` . In this fnThread() I want to create a shared_from_this() and pass it to listening parties with a signal. But the line `boost::shared_ptr<foo> p = shared_from_this()` throws an exception as follows;

```
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> > at memory location 0x04c2f720.
```

The offending command is shared_from_this() . Is it illegal to create a `shared_from_this()` from another thread or am I doing something wrong ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

PS: I plan on changing my signal arguments to plain pointers as it wouldn't affect my structure. But I favor shared_ptr<> and I want to hear any comments about the decision. Maybe it's a bad choice for this particular situation. What do you suggest ?

EDIT:

Here is a simple class for you to test

```
class foo : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<foo>
{
public:
    int start()
    {
        foo_thread.reset(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&foo::fn_foo_thread, this)));

        return 0;
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        if (foo_thread->joinable())
            foo_thread->join();
    }

private:
    boost::scoped_ptr<boost::thread> foo_thread;

    void fn_foo_thread()
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<foo> p = shared_from_this();
        std::cout << "foo thread terminated. \n" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean, "create a `shared_from_this()`?"

Comment: I mean getting 'boost::shared_ptr<foo>' to 'this'

Comment: Please show us the code that instantiates `foo` and calls `start`. The mistake is likely there.

Comment: I found the source of the error. In a function, I "pop" the object from a deque and call the start method on it. As soon as the function returns, the only instance of this object goes out of scope but the thread continues to run and crashes as it tries get a 'shared_from_this()'. Stupid mistake...

Answer (score 4):

`shared_from_this` can be used from another thread. The `bad_weak_ptr` exception is thrown when there exists no `shared_ptr` to `this` (as the name implies). Most likely your problem exists elsewhere in your code.

Comment: What about calling `shared_from_this` on an object from multiple threads concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by @Sam Miller, the problem exists elsewhere. I can imagine that you declared `foo` to be a `scoped_ptr<foo>`. By doing like that, it's impossible for `shared_from_this` to return a valid shared pointer because a smart pointer of type `boost::scoped_ptr` can’t transfer ownership of an object. Here the reason of your exception.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to consider changing `boost::shared_ptr<>` to `boost::intrusive_ptr<>`. The main difference is that `boost::intrusive_ptr<>` suggests that the reference counter is stored inside the object (although it is possible to store it elsewhere). With embedded reference counter you can construct an `boost::intrusive_ptr<>` from this in constructor or from a plain pointer whenever you please (but don't take `boost::intrusive_ptr<>` from this in the destructor).

Answer (score 0):

`shared_from_this()` cannot be called before the constructor finishes, or after the destructor starts.